# Security of Half-Key Key Management Scheme

Tags: key-exchange

I am interested in algorithms that consume as less space available on a memory, for low consuming power devices such as wireless nodes. From a search I have found this article here:

https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2103380.2103433?download=true

I have read it but I cannot understand where it is based in order to provide security. It is not the common discrete logarithm problem, elliptic curves etc. Can this scheme, as it is described in the paper, work in other circumstances?

Comment: What I am asking is very new and the information I ask are very little over google, I cannot understand the downvoting....

Comment: A read of the intro gives "random key pre-distribution scheme". You can even find a Wikipedia link on this.

Comment: Please do follow up on your answers and don't ask questions that don't show prior effort. I see you haven't accepted any answer on any SE site. That's not considered proper conduct. And please do not cross post.